Configure source-generated JSON serialization for all types in assembly
I'm building ASP.NET Web API for AOT publishing and need to configure source-generated JSON serialization for it, as reflection-based serialization will not work for AOT.
According to documentation I created AppJsonSerializerContext class with JsonSerializable attribute like this:
[JsonSerializable(typeof(MyType1[]))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(MyType2[]))]
[JsonSerializable(typeof(MyType3[]))]
internal sealed partial class AppJsonSerializerContext : JsonSerializerContext
{
}

This works, but in a big production application there can be a lot of types that should be serializable. And then the AppJsonSerializerContext will have a long list of JsonSerizable attributes.
How to configure the serialization for multiple types at once without boilerplate code? Maybe it could be generated for all types of a given assembly?
